# How does the position of the .frame() modifier affect the view?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm beginner in SwiftUI and I had some misunderstanding with the .frame() modifier.

I want to create a right-aligned image, so I'm doing this:

```
Image(systemName: "xmark")
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  .padding(5)
  .background(.gray)
  .mask(Circle())
  .padding()
```

But the image appears in the center of my screen. I changed my code to this:

```
Image(systemName: "xmark")
  .padding(5)
  .background(.gray)
  .mask(Circle())
  .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
  .padding()
```

And it works the way I want it to, but I'm so confused as to why this code works. Can someone explain to me why this code works and the previous one doesn't?

I also see that people write code like that:

```
VStack {
  ...
}
.padding()
.frame(maxWidth: 200)
.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
```

Does that even make sense? Aren't we redefining maxWidth with the second .frame() modifier?